# I want to create U.S. Date Format to Indian Date Format Using Asp MVC Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to Create Date Format the US to Indian Date Format like`(dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm tt)`.

When I run the code on my local machine it works.

When we publish and fetch values from the server at that time it shows "US" Date Format`(mm/dd/yyyy)`

How τo do the internal conversion, in Appsettings.json what strings i need to mention.

```
 public static DateTime ConvertIndianDateFormat(DateTime usTime)
 {
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        TimeZoneInfo usEasternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Eastern Standard Time"); 
        TimeZoneInfo indianZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"); 
        DateTime usEasternTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(usTime, usEasternZone);
        DateTime indianTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(usTime, indianZone);

        return indianTime;
 }
```

Comment: So... How do you print the date, and what have you tried?

Comment: public static DateTime ConvertIndianDateFormat(DateTime usTime) { DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now; TimeZoneInfo usEasternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Eastern Standard Time"); TimeZoneInfo indianZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"); DateTime usEasternTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(usTime, usEasternZone); DateTime indianTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(usTime, indianZone); return indianTime; }

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values. Formats apply only to *strings*. There's nothing to convert. If you want to display a date using the US or Indian string format, just use the correct CultureInfo in the `ToString` or `String.Format` call, eg `DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("in-IN"))`

Comment: The *default* culture depends on the application type, eg in a desktop application,it's the current user's locale. In web apps, ASP.NET Core may try to detect the end user's locale from the language selection, you can hard-code a locale in the settings,you can specify it at the page or request level. You can do all this declaratively or programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are probably using something like `DateTime.Now` for C# and if you have an SQL Server you are using `GETDATE()`. It's not like an issue with application.json or something. The above functions return the machine datetime, thus why locally on your pc the time is correct and incorrect if you upload it to a server.

So make sure that the time is correct. If you are uploading to servers in another country then you will probably have a different time and/or format.

How you proceed depends on your needs:

**Is the time correct?**

Then simply reformated it or store it specifically using

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm tt") // this is not the correct format.
```

**Do you want to serve multiple clients in multiple regions/countries?**

Then you should store the time as UTC and cast it based on clients date format. For example the server could be in USA and someone from UK would view a different time than his own which would be weird.

```
DateTime.UtcNow
```

Generally your problem could be large or small depending on your needs

Comment: We are using azure For Documents. When users can uploading the Document it Create's Current Date From India. But it in production it Showing USA Date Format.

Comment: The OP asks about some non-existed DateTime format, not the offset

Comment: @narayanareddy dates have no formats. There's no USA format.  It's *your* code generating a string using a specific culture - the end user's, the application's or a custom one.

Comment: In User Interface it showing US Timing. I mean Current India Time was (6:00 AM). In Us (12:00 PM). Time variance.